# Properly formatting numbers in pygal

Tags: python, flask, formatting, pygal

I'm using `Pygal` (with `Python` / `Flask`) relatively successfully in regards to loading data, formatting colors, min/max, etc., but can't figure out how to format a number in `Pygal` using dollar signs and commas.

I'm getting 265763.557372895 and instead want $265,763.

This goes for both the pop-up boxes when hovering over a data point, as well as the y-axes.

I've looked through pygal.org's documentation to no avail.  Does anyone know how to properly format those numbers?

UPDATE:

I'm not quite ready to mark this question "answered" as I still can't get the separating commas.  However, I did find the following native formatting option in pygal.  This eliminates trailing decimals (without using Python's int()) and adds a dollar sign:

`graph.value_formatter = lambda y: "$%.0f" % y`

Change the `0f` to `2f` if you prefer two decimals, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

graph.value_formatter = lambda y: "{:,}".format(y) will get you the commas.

graph.value_formatter = lambda y: "${:,}".format(y) will get you the commas and the dollar sign.
Note that this formatting seems to be valid for Python 2.7 but would not work on 2.6.

Comment: And `.value_formatter = lambda y: "${:,.0f}".format(y)` will eliminate the trailing decimals.  Thank you Sam!